# Spring Thymeleaf - How to pass an objects ID from html page to the controller?

Tags: java, html, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

In my application the user is show a list of exam objects and they select one to edit. 
When they click the edit link it brings them to a HTML page where the URL contains that exams ID.

I would like to know how to pass the id of the exam to the controller. 
I'm getting this error: "Missing URI template variable 'id' for method parameter of type Long"

I would also like to know how to make existing values appear in the forms text boxses.

HTML allSubjects.html where the user selects a subject to edit: (this all works)

```
    <h4> exams:</h4>
<div th:each="exam : ${subject.exam}"> 
<h4 th:text="${exam.examTitle}"/>
<a th:href="@{/editExam.html(id=${exam.examId})}">Edit Exam</a>
```

Edit exam HTML:

```
<form action="#" th:action="@{/editExam.html{examId}}"  th:object="${exam}" method="put">


    <table>
        <tr>
        <td> Exam Title:</td>
         <td><input type="text" th:field="*{examTitle}" th:text="${exam.examTitle}"/></td>
    <!--    <td th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('examTitlee')}" th:errors="*{examTitle}">error message</td>  --> 
        </tr>  
        <tr>
            <td> Exam grade worth </td>
            <td><input th:field="*{examGradeWorth}" /></td>
        <!--    <td th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('examGradeWorth')}" th:errors="*{examGradeWorth}">error message</td> -->
            </tr>  
            <tr>
                <td>examGradeAchieved</td>
                <td><input th:field="*{examGradeAchieved}"/></td>
                </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><button type="submit">Submit post</button></td>
                </tr>
    </table>
    </div>
</form>
```

My controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/editExam.html{examId}", method = { RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.PUT })
public String editExam(@ModelAttribute("exam") @PathVariable(value = "id")Long examId, @RequestBody Exam exam,Model model, BindingResult result) {

         examRepository.findOne(examId);
            model.addAttribute("examTitle", exam.getExamTitle());
            model.addAttribute("examGradeWorth", exam.getExamGradeWorth());
            model.addAttribute("examGradeAchieved", exam.getExamGradeAchieved());


    exam.setExamTitle(exam.getExamTitle());
         exam.setExamGradeWorth(exam.getExamGradeWorth());
         exam.setExamGradeAchieved(exam.getExamGradeAchieved());

         examRepository.save(exam);

    return "editExam";
}
```

WHen I try to run all the above code just to see if the form displays I get the following error: Missing URI template variable 'id' for method parameter of type String

Comment: Well, you have `{examId}` but no `{id}`. That said, the standard way to express what you want is `/exam/{id}/edit`. (And if you're using Spring Data Commons, you can just use `@PathVariable("id") Exam exam` as a controller parameter.)

Comment: @chrylis Thank you, could you please explain and show where I am to make those changes? I don't really understand your comment.

Comment: You really should read [the Spring reference documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web.html), especially about URI templates (which are a RFC standard). You may not get some of what the docs are talking about yet, but the important stuff will click, and the rest will make sense once you put the pieces together, and you'll know where to look for what you need.

Comment: @chrylis Cheers for sharing that document. I changed value = "Id") in the controller to value = "examId") and it got rid of the error.